# MySQL Comparison Query

Tags: mysql, comparison

I need to compare all regions and show the better regions about the score. For example if I want to see Asia's Score Comparison; I will see only the better regions about the score. (better regions: North America, Europe)

```
select
    Destination_Region,
    count(1) as Score
from pro11
    where 
        Destination_Region is not null
    group by 
        Destination_Region 
    order by 
        Score DESC;
```

**Query Result:**

```
Europe             1069737
North America      218302
Asia               140452
Middle East        70899
Africa             33901
Oceania            28701
South America      24815
Caribbeans         16550
```

So if I want to see Africa's comparison results; I should see the Middle East, Asia, North America, Europe. I will make the query dynamic, you could pick a region and use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yep, I don't know how to it with Mysql.

Comment: I think you can use self-join to achieve this, will post the query soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it using `HAVING` clause:

```
select
    Destination_Region,
    count(*) as Score
from pro11
    where 
        Destination_Region is not null
    group by 
        Destination_Region 
    having  Score>(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pro11 WHERE Destination_Region = 'Africa' GROUP BY Destination_Region)
    order by Score DESC;
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ea930/1).